# What is causing a white rash to appear on sacred fig leaves?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, plant-health, leaves

[image: Fig leaves with many small white spots]

Hey, I have planted a sacred fig seed a couple of months ago. It's growing fantastically, but lately its leaves have started developing these tiny white spots all over them. New leaves develop normally at first and the problem only starts when they reach maturity.

What is causing this and how can I take care of it?